# heave writing to InnoDB

Tags: mysql, performance, innodb

We are constructing, for every day, mappings from tweet user id to the list of tweet ids of tweets made by that user. The storage engine we are using is Percona xtraDB "5.1.63-rel13.4 Percona Server (GPL), 13.4, Revision 443"

We are unsatisfied with the maximal throughput in terms of row inserts per second. Our maximal throughput to process tweets with xtraDB is around 6000 ~ 8000 tweets per second. (for example, if we had to rebuild data for some day from scratch, we'll have to wait for almost a day)

For the most part we are able to do this realtime enough with the full amount of twitter data (which is roughly 4000 ~ 5000 tweets per second).

We have narrowed down the bottleneck of our application to MySQL InnoDB insert. In our application, we read the feed from the disk and parse it with jackson (which happens at about 30,000 tweets per second). Our application then proceeds in batches of tweets. For the set of authors that generates these tweets, we partitioning them into 8 groups (simple partitioning with user id modulo 8). A table is allocated for each group and 1 thread is allocated to write the data to that table. Everyday there are roughly 26 million unique users that generates these tweets, and therefore each table have roughly 4 millions rows.
For a group of users, we only use one transaction for read and update. The group size is a runtime tunable. We have tried various sizes from 8 ~ 64000 , and we have determined 256 to be a good batch size.

the schema of our table is

```
CREATE TABLE `2012_07_12_g0` (  `userid` bigint(20) NOT NULL,  `tweetId` longblob,  PRIMARY KEY (`userid`)) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

where tweetId is the compressed list of tweet ids long integers, compressed with Google snappy

Each thread uses

```
Select userid,tweetId from <tablename> where userid IN (....)
```

to resolve the userids to readback the data, and the threads use

```
INSERT INTO <tablename> (userid,tweetId) VALUES (...) ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE tweetId=VALUES(tweetId)
```

to update the rows with new tweetids.

We have tried setting various XtraDB parameters

```
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 2
innodb_max_dirty_pages_pct = 80
innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT
innodb_doublewrite = 0
innodb_use_purge_thread = 1
innodb_thread_concurrency = 32
innodb_write_io_threads = 8
innodb_read_io_threads = 8 
#innodb_io_capacity = 20000 
#innodb_adaptive_flushing = 1
#innodb_flush_neighbor_pages= 0"
```

The table size for each day is roughly 8G for all tables, and InnoDB is given 24GB to work with.

We are using:

- 6-disk (crucial m4 SSD, 512 GB, 000F firmware) software RAID5.
- Mysql innodb data, table space on the SSD partition
- ext4 mount with noatime,nodiratime,commit=60
- centos 6.2
- sun jdk 1.6.30

Any tips for making our insert go faster would be greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: What indexes do you have on the table ? Is it possible to reduce the number of indexes to speed up writes?

Comment: we only query using the primary key

Comment: So does that mean you only have a primary key index ? I'm asking because additional indexes slow down writes as every single write recreates each index.

Comment: yes, we do not declare any other index in SQL.

Comment: Okay, well this is probably kind of useless but you are losing some performance due to using RAID5. Might want to migrate to RAID10 unless space is a constraint.

Comment: we have benchmarked our disk throughput with fio, using 8k ~ 128k distributed block sizes, we can write about 800MB per second.

Using iotop, it shows at any given time, mysql writes at best 100MB persecond (often less, around 50MB per second)

Answer (score 0):

My initial suggestions would be:

1. As you don't have RAID card with memory you may want to comment out **innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT** line to let system cache writes
2. as you disabled double write buffer you could also set **innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit** to 0 which would be faster than 2
3. set **innodb_log_buffer_size** to cover at least one second of writes (approx 12Mb for 30K tweets)
4. in case you use binary logs - make sure you have **sync_binlog = 0**

On the hardware side I would strongly suggest to try RAID card with at least 256Mb RAM and battery unit (BBU) to improve write speed. There are RAID cards on the market that supports SSD.

Hope this helps. Please let me know how it goes.

Comment: I have commented out innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT and left it as default. I will report back how that works.

Comment: Thanks! Did you considered to change innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit and innodb_log_buffer_size as well?

Comment: my settings right now are :
innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M
innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0

Comment: With 
    innodb_log_buffer_size = 4M 
    innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit = 0
we still tops at around 10,000 insert per second
[link] http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=zaVLfUyS

thoughts ?

Comment: as a blind guess - try to set innodb_log_buffer_size to 12M. Next step is to check OS, MySQL and InnoDB counters in dynamic. Let's start with iostat -dx 3 5 and vmstat 3 5 - please let me know the output

Comment: thanks. Here are the output for vmstat and iostat:
    [link] http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=F4SARxnF
    [link] http://pastebin.com/raw.php?i=3Ka1LYE0

md0 is the raid5 device (sdd ~ sdi, 6 disks)

Comment: so 7K IOPS, 40MBps per disk which is not even 1/2 of disk capacity so bottleneck is on MySQL (which is probably the case) or md0 device or in filesystem (which is unlikely). There are few possible sources - innodb insert mutex, log buffer, buffer_pool mutex and few others. I would need some statics and config file to be sure. How urgent is the problem? It's kinda weekend :)

Comment: One more clarification. Do you use batch inserts INSERT INTO ... VALUES (...), (...), (...), (...) or performing multiple inserts in batch?

Comment: thanks. Yes I use batched SELECT ( userid IN (?,?,?,?,...) )  and batched INSERT . (VALUES (?,?),(?,?)..)   
the batch size we use is 256

Comment: here is the relevant section of my.cnf : [link](http://pastebin.com/akHEFR0f)

We have tried several things : 
1) batch insert size of 8 ~ 4096 , the best value seem to be around 100 ~ 200. Our program uses 8 concurrent writer threads. Each thread would use  batch insert

2) when reading the data from database, we tried several transaction levels (read uncommited, or no transaction). This does not help with our performance.

Comment: SHOW INNODB STATUS\G and mysqladmin -i 10 -c 3 -r extended-status output would be good to have.

Answer (score 0):

> InnoDB is given 24GB

Do you mean this is the innodb_buffer_pool_size? You didn't say how much memory you have nor what CPUs you are using. If so then you should probably be using a larger innodb_log_buffer_size. What's your setting for innodb_log_file_size? It should probably be in the region of 96Mb.

> innodb_write_io_threads = 8

ISTR that ext3 has some concurrency problems with multiple writers - but I don't know about ext4

Have you tried changing innodb_flush_method?

Which I/O scheduler are you using (in the absence of a smart disk controller, usually deadline is fastest, sometimes CFQ)?

Switching off the ext4 barriers will help with throughput - its a bit more risky - make sure you've got checksums enabled in JBD2. Similarly setting innodb_flush_log_at_trx_commit=0 should give a significant increase but more risky.

Since you're obviously not bothered about maintaining your data in a relational format, then you might consider using a noSQL database.

Comment: We have "Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5630  @ 2.53GHz", 96GB DDR3 memory. We are using deadline scheduler.
Yes you are correct, by 24GB I was refering to the innodb buffer pool size.
I have commented out innodb_flush_method = O_DIRECT and left it as default. I will report back how that works.

Comment: Our log file size is 256MB, the log buffer size is 4MB

Comment: log buffer should probably be a bit bigger.